# Don't have option to choose XML as source in AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to learn AWS Glue. I have an XML in S3 that I need to use as the source.

However, I don't have an option to choose `XML` as the data format. Why?

These are my only options:
[image]

How can I parse XML in AWS Glue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI interface of Glue Studio does not [support XML](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/edit-jobs-source-s3-files.html) yet. You would have to edit the script manually to read XML files.